# Display input box if selecting a specific radio button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Goal:
If you select green in the radio. a input box text  will appear below the radio input group. If you click another radio button, it will not displayed.

If you select blue in the radio. a input box text  will appear below the radio input group. If you click another radio button, it will not displayed.

Problem:
I do not how to solve it. How would you solve it?

Info:
*Newbie in reactjs

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rpncls?

Thank you!

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      color: 'red'
    };

    this.onRadioChange = this.onRadioChange.bind(this);
  }

  onRadioChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      color: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <strong>Select Color:</strong>

          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="red"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'red'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Red</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="green"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'green'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Green</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="blue"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'blue'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Blue</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="orange"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'orange'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Ornage</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="purple"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'purple'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Purple</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <button type="submit">Choose Color</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally render the text box depending on the color selected.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      color: 'red'
    };

    this.onRadioChange = this.onRadioChange.bind(this);
  }

  onRadioChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      color: e.target.value
    });
  };

  textBoxVisible = () => {
    return (this.state.color==="green" || this.state.color==="blue");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <strong>Select Color:</strong>

          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="red"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'red'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Red</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="green"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'green'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Green</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="blue"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'blue'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Blue</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="orange"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'orange'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Ornage</span>
              </label>
            </li>

            <li>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="purple"
                  checked={this.state.color === 'purple'}
                  onChange={this.onRadioChange}
                />
                <span>Purple</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {this.textBoxVisible() && <input type="text"/>}
          <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Choose Color</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

To make sure the text box and the submit button aren't on the same line, add this to style.css:

```
.submitButton{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
const OPTIONS_DATA = [
      { id: "red", label: "Red", isEditable: false, isChecked: true },
      { id: "green", label: "Green", isEditable: false, isChecked: false },
      { id: "blue", label: "Blue", isEditable: false, isChecked: false },
      { id: "orange", label: "Orange", isEditable: false, isChecked: false }
    ];
    
    export const App = () => {
      const [options, setOptions] = React.useState(OPTIONS_DATA);
    
      const handleChange = (evt) => {
        const id = evt.target.value;
        const formatOptions = options.map((opt) => {
          if (opt.id === id) {
            return {
              ...opt,
              isChecked: true,
              isEditable: true
            };
          }
          return { ...opt, isChecked: false, isEditable: false };
        });
        setOptions(formatOptions);
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <form>
            <strong>Select Color:</strong>
            <ul>
              {options.map((item) => (
                <li>
                  <label>
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value={item.id}
                      checked={item.isChecked}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <span>{item.label}</span>
                  </label>
                  {item.isEditable && <input placeholder="Hello There" />}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
    
            <button type="submit">Choose Color</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
```